# Value of pointer when address of the pointer not initialized

Tags: c++, pointers

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int a;
    int *p = &a;
    std::cout << *p << "\n";
}
```

In this program, when I leave `a` uninitialized and try getting the output
of the pointer, it gives me `-2`. But when I initialize `a` with a value, printing `*p` gives me that value. Why does it give `-2` when I leave `a` uninitialized?

Comment: John Bradshaw Layfield, is that you?

Comment: [Nasal demons!](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Nasal_demons)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because using uninitialized variables, whether direct or indirect (through a pointer or reference), is [***undefined behavior<sup>[1][2][3]</sup>***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior).

---

<sup>[1]</sup> <sub>This basically means that those uninitialized variables would have indeterminate values.</sub>
<sup>[2]</sup> <sub>I'm sure you'll never like [***undefined behavior***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) anywhere in your code.</sub> 
<sup>[3]</sup> <sub>Golden rule: beware of [***undefined behavior***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unspecified_behavior).</sub>

Answer (score 1):

**a** is allocated on stack. It contains whatever was there by chance, when it got allocated. Unlike global, local variables in **C** are not implicitly initialized to 0 (or anything else).

Probably if you run program multiple times, it will give different value (or not).

Answer (score 0):

it is illegal in c++ to assign a pointer to a undefined value . `a` is uninitialized . When you are dereferencing it , it just points to a garbage value .